# Xcode 11 hangs during Archive on CocoaPods task

Tags: xcode, development, archive

After updating Xcode, when archiving my iOS app, it hangs on a specific CocoaPods task (GEOSwift). Archiving just continues for an indeterminate time (I can let it work for hours without results).

[image]

Solutions found for similar issues on previous Xcode versions (none works):

> • Remove armv7 from Valid architectures ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55376236/8520417))
>
> • Change debug information format to DWARF instead of DWARF with dSYM File ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55376236/8520417))
>
> • Changing Compilation Mode from Whole Module to Incremental ([seen here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115303))
>
> • Changing Optimization Level from Optimize for Speed to either Optimize for Size or No Optimization ([seen here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115303))
>
> • Flip Exclusive Access to Memory to *Full Enforcement (Runtime Checks in Debug Builds Only)* ([seen here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115303))
>
> • Changing the SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL from the PodFile ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070872/8520417))

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Updating to Xcode 11.1 doesn't help.